# where is the error in my if statement code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request, response

I have a problem that I send a request to a page and when I get the response which is a string something get wrong

This is the code request :

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     url:'../admin/parsers/check_address.php',
     method:'post',
     data :data,//data that is been requested   
     success:function(data){
         if(data != 'passed'){

             jQuery('#payment-errors').html(data);
         }
         if(data=='passed'){
            alert(data);
         }
     },//this data is which is coming back from response
     error:function(){alert('حدث خطأ ما');},

 });
```

and this is the code of the response :

```
echo 'passed';
```

even though the response contains the string 'passed' but it does not go into the if statement

```
if(data=='passed'){
                alert(data);
             }
```

so where is the fault in my code and thank you in advance

Comment: this question is not duplicated

Comment: Ah... My bad... I am happy to open the question. @Ibrahim Would you like to make the question readable?

Comment: @Ibrahim Did you check if there are any errors in the console? Did you see what's coming up in the Network tab?

Comment: @Ibrahim Please do [edit] your question to include what debugging steps you've taken. For instance, look at the Network tab to see exactly what the response to the request is.

Comment: yes it is but ...I get the string 'passed' from the response but why the if statement if(data != 'passed'){ get into it not if(data=='passed')

Comment: I look at the Network tab to see the respone and it was the string 'passed' !!!

Comment: Your program is waiting for a JSON object, not for a string. Try to JSON encode your response. I am sure PHP has a function to make this.

Answer (score 1):

Good possibility there is some extra whitespace at either end of the string also (due to whitespace in php file)

Try trimming the response:

```
if(data.trim() == 'passed'){
```

In general it is easier to use JSON than strings for such requests

Comment: thanks for helping...but it does not work..there is not any extra whitespaces

Comment: you sure? Is a common problem. What does `data.length` return? Also what is content type header being sent?

Comment: well 86 sure is a lot longer than length of "passed" which is 6. Use JSON....much cleaner

Comment: yes it is...but why is this happening???????....and then how to use JSON in my state?

Comment: no idea why without seeing exactly what is in whole response or the php code used. What does `data.trim().length` return?

Comment: how could i show you the whole code...becaues may be i will not sleep without knowing hhhhhh

Comment: so what is the trimmed length then?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer should be a JSON object, not a string. Try to do the following:

#### In your PHP program:

```
echo json_encode(array('resp' => 'passed'))
```

#### In your Javascript code:

```
if(data.resp != 'passed'){
    jQuery('#payment-errors').html(data.resp);
}
    alert(data.resp);
}
```

By the way, if something is not `!=` then it is `==`. You may surely simplify your else condition as I did.

Comment: also should set `dataType` in `$.ajax`

Comment: Yes, it would be good. But I think it defaults to JSON. I'm not sure about this, so... better safe than sorry.

Comment: no it does not. It uses *"intelligent guess"* as per docs.  It will if appropriate header set server side though. Safer to set it

Comment: hey charlietfl  the data.trim().length return 75